# Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification in VIte / React project

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollupjs

When I ran `npm run build` I get this warning:

`(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:`

`- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application`

`- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks`

`- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.`

`✓ built in 4.03s`

I actually tried to implement lazy loading but it does not work, how can I fix this without modifying the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Code-splitting can be addressed at "splitting code into smaller verion of its own", instead of having file with 200 lines, you can splitting its into 4 files with 50 lines each.

Also, you can try lazy-loading with React's Docs example:

```js
import { lazy } from 'react';
const MarkdownPreview = lazy(() => import('./MarkdownPreview.js'));
```

usage:

```js
<Suspense fallback={<MyLoadingComponent />}>
    <MarkdownPreview />
</Suspense>
```

if you having function that are only using when having interaction:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    import('./myFunction').then((res) => {
    // your logic
    });
}
```